# Menu bar for Thunderbird

Tags: unity, thunderbird, appmenu

I installed 11.04 today and I seem to be missing the menu bar in Thunderbird. I don't have either the integrated menu bar in the top panel or any other menu option. Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should have the Global Menu Bar Integration addon installed. Did you install Thunderbird manually?

Try [installing the thunderbird-globalmenu package](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/thunderbird-globalmenu) from the software center and then restarting Thunderbird.

Comment: I didn't install Thunderbird manually, but I did upgrade from 10.10 to 11.04, not a clean install. Uninstalling and reinstalling Thunderbird and thunderbird-globalmenu and rebooting fixed my problem. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Needed a full ``apt-get remove thunderbird thunderbird-globalmenu ; apt-get install thunderbird thunderbird-globalmenu`` here also, the ``--reinstall`` was not enough. No reboot needed although.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem on a fresh install of 11.04. It was really frustrating to not be able to unmaximize Thunderbird. Workarounds such as alt-Tab and alt-space allowed switching between applications, but there was no way to put the Thunderbird window side-by-side with that of another application. The problem persisted after an upgrade to 11.10.

The good news is that I found I only had to reinstall thunderbird-globalmenu via synaptic to fix it. I haven't waited to make sure it stays fixed, yet.

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar problem in that I would lose the menu after opening and closing Thunderbird a few times whenever Minimize to Tray Revived was activated.

A workaround was to actually disable Global Menu Bar Integration. Then you use Thunderbird's native menu when Minimize to Tray crashes Unity's.

Answer (score 0):

Update - The problem came back after restoring the app from the messaging menu. The problem seems to be with an extension I was using. The minimize to tray extension does not seem to work properly with Unity. I will file a bug report with the dev. Uninstalling that extension fixed my problem.